# Form date input from(date) to(date) or I don't know for one or both choices

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Hi Im new in coding and I have some training project which include MySQL database input from HTML form.
Its like log of games you played. 1st date input is when you start play and second date input is when you finished game. But I need checker or something similar for both options like "I don't know".
So displayed information can look like: From: unknown - To: 2019-12-06.

How I make form for this? My MySQL columns are from, to, do I need more? And how I display unknown with PHP if one date is empty?

Comment: These are all really rather questions you should try and answer for yourself, by working through a couple of beginner’s tutorials. You can ask about _specific_ problems with code you have written here, but this is not a teaching ground.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to do a beginner course but to help you right now I would take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp as it talks about how to format date.

There are a couple of other links. The from date should not be blank. You could just get the current date. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_current_date.asp

I would also check out the Date_ADD() function to see about adding Unknown to the date.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp

It could be easier to set both to the current date and update the finished game date for each day they play the game until it is fully complete.